# Is it possible to open a mobile browser with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, web-application, mobile-automation, mobile-applications

I know it is possible to open a desktop web browser with Selenium WeDriver.
The following lines written in Java allows doing so:

```
WebDriver webDriverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
webDriverChrome.get(pagesToTest[i]);
```

At the same time we can debug web application on mobile browsers using inspect screen while mobile devices are connected via USB:

[image]

[image]

**The question is:**

Is it possible to automate the inspection of web pages via mobile browsers using real devices with Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: could you add more infromation on how you are debuggin mobile browser , please add the configuration infromationn

Comment: What configuration do you require? Browser versions and devices?

Comment: how are you debugging mobile browser in desktop

Comment: Via the page which is displayed on the first screen. "inspect" button.

Comment: that will just open chrome dev tools right ? and you can seelct different screen size not the actual chrome browser runnign on a mobile device if i am not worng

Comment: @PDHide --- It is possible to inspect chrome running on a mobile phone.  Try plugging an android phone into a laptop and going to this URL --- chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging got it let me have a look

Comment: Did you try the answer ?

Comment: Not yet but I will. Have some immediate priorities at the work.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer is yes , you dont need appium .**

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android

Thanks for the wonderful question

You can run chrome in android device straight from selenium:

First make sure adb version is latest:

download latest from :
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

the adb will be inside the platform tool

**Now make sure device detected**

run:

```
adb devices
```

**And make sure device shows in the list**

[image]

make sure it is showing device and not unauthorized:

**Now you can run below code:**

**python:**

you can add experimental option (for any binding )

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

**You can see how to inspect from desktop here:**

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging#troubleshooting
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is "Appium".  Appium is very similar to Selenium WebDriver, except you will need to update the desired capabilities in order to work with the mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. It is possible to automate the inspection of **web pages** via mobile browsers using real devices with Selenium WebDriver. [Appium](https://appium.io/) can help you the most.

Appium is an open source test automation framework for use with native, hybrid and mobile web apps. NO dependency on Mobile device OS. It has framework or wrapper that translate Selenium Webdriver commands into UIAutomation (iOS) or UIAutomator (Android) commands depending on the device type, not any OS type.

Appium supports all languages that have Selenium client libraries like- Java, Objective-C, JavaScript with node.js, PHP, Ruby, Python, C#, etc.